# cant appear only the max date for a number of transactions

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, date, mysql-workbench

I execute this query:

```
SELECT distinct(accounts.account_id), transactions.trn_code , transactions.trn_date
FROM accounts join transactions ON accounts.account_id = transactions.account_id
WHERE accounts.account_currency = 'USD'  AND accounts.account_cards_linked > 1 
AND transactions.trn_date >= '2015/03/01' AND transactions.trn_date <= '2015/03/31'
GROUP BY transactions.trn_code , transactions.trn_date,accounts.account_id
HAVING transactions.trn_date >= MAX(transactions.trn_date)
ORDER BY accounts.account_id;
```

and I get these results:
[click image to see the result grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybxqV.jpg)

My problem is that I want for each one account to appear only the transaction with the latest date. But now if an account has more than one transaction, there are all appeared.  (for example, I want the account 912...129 to appears only one time with the latest day,2015/03/05. (see the image for the example))
Any ideas??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do a `JOIN` on `MAX(trn_date)` of each account:

```
SELECT
    a.account_id,
    t.trn_code,
    t.trn_date
FROM accounts a
INNER JOIN transactions t
    ON a.account_id = t.account_id
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        account_id, MAX(trn_date) AS trn_date
    FROM transactions
    WHERE
        trn_date >= '2015/03/01' 
        AND trn_date <= '2015/03/31'
    GROUP BY account_id
)td
    ON t.account_id = td.account_id
    AND t.trn_date = td.trn_date
WHERE
    a.account_currency = 'USD'
    AND a.account_cards_linked > 1 
ORDER BY a.account_id
```

*Note: Use meaningful table aliases to improve readability and maintainability.*

Answer (score 2):

Select Max(trn_date) and remove the date from the group by

```
SELECT distinct(accounts.account_id), transactions.trn_code , MAX(transactions.trn_date)
FROM accounts join transactions ON accounts.account_id = transactions.account_id
WHERE accounts.account_currency = 'USD'  AND accounts.account_cards_linked > 1 
AND transactions.trn_date >= '2015/03/01' AND transactions.trn_date <= '2015/03/31'
GROUP BY transactions.trn_code , accounts.account_id
HAVING transactions.trn_date >= MAX(transactions.trn_date)
ORDER BY accounts.account_id;
```

Comment: I get this error:
Error code: 1054. Unkown column 'transactions.trn_date' in 'having clause'

Comment: and no need `having` i think

Comment: @Thodoris Yeah, try without the having clause

Comment: I don't think this works, because if there are two trn_code's on the same day, you'll get two rows for the account number, rather than 1 as requested.

Comment: @JohnBingham u are right:/ 
I run this without having and I get the same results as before

Answer (score 1):

So I think it should be using subquery like that, in case account_id is `unique`

```
SELECT a.account_id, t.trn_code , t.trn_date
FROM accounts a
inner join transactions t ON a.account_id = t.account_id
WHERE (a.account_id, t.trn_date) 
        in (SELECT ac.account_id, max(ts.trn_date)
            FROM accounts ac
            inner join transactions ts ON ac.account_id = ts.account_id
            WHERE ac.account_currency = 'USD'  AND ac.account_cards_linked > 1 
            AND ts.trn_date between '2015/03/01' and '2015/03/31'
            GROUP BY ac.account_id
        )
ORDER BY a.account_id;
```